# Gmail "Layouts Tool" configurable via appscript?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api, google-workspace

With the imminent rollout of Mail-merge tags in Email Layouts Tool per [workspace blog](https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2024/03/create-fully-customized-email-campaigns-new-layout-tool.html), and knowing [mail-merge works with appscript](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/samples/automations/mail-merge), will layout objects be accessible/configurable via appscript? I see no api/service documentation mentioning the email layouts tool.

Attempting to dump many third party apps that require customer name and customer specific details. Want to learn the ropes with our shipping notifications which requires customer name (mail-merge tag or sheets cell), order number (sheets cell), carrier name (sheets cell), unique tracking link (shipper API) as a link on a button in the layout, and unique arrival date (shipper API) in the layout. [Email Layouts Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIKWv.png)